# How to plot multiple dates in single bar plot side by side?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, bar-chart

I have the data of some products ID, order date (month), and delivery date(month).
I have to plot in one graph showing the difference of when the order was taken and when delivered.

```
ID    Order date(month)      Delivery date(month)
1     2018-04                2018-04
2     2018-06                2018-07
3     2018-07                2018-08
4     2019-02                2019-06
```

I am able to make bar plot for one column at a time, How can I represent both bars side by side in same graph so its comparable?
I did this for now,
[image]

I need to change the dots to bars as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use separate y values(in this case order and delivery dates) and x values(date) in different lines. this will create one plot with 2 y values and then use bar graphs for both of them

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(date, order, 'b-') #here b- denotes color and type
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(date, Delivery, 'g-')
```

or use the barh method with specified width for horizontal bars